# Windows: list of open files for non-ascii filenames

Tags: windows, unicode, scripting

I'm writing a windows script and I'm trying to get the list of open-files for a specific process. Sysinternals' `handle.exe` seems to work fine but *only* for ascii filenames. For non-ascii chars it prints question marks. It's not an issue with how cmd.exe displays things; handle.exe replaces non-ascii chars with "?" (character 0x3F)[1].

---

**Note [1]** `dir` on the same cmd.exe displays filenames just fine. To be 100% sure I've issued this command `handle.exe > c:\temp.txt` and then viewed temp.txt with a hex editor. It really had bytes 0x3F in place of non-ascii chars.

Comment: Looks like `handle.exe` is an ANSI-application, and not Unicode-enabled.

Comment: Emphasis on ANSI, not ASCII. Go `chcp`. handle.exe should display all the characters in the corresponding character set normally. Try PowerShell?

Comment: handle.exe is hard-coded to use ANSI output. It doesn't use the console codepage.

Comment: Windows comes with openfiles.exe, which will work, except it requires enabling a kernel option to maintain object lists. This can be enabled with the command `openfiles /local on` and rebooting. The command to create the list is `openfiles /query`. Use the `/v` for verbose mode, which includes the PID in addition to the process name. Use the `/fo` option to change the output format to `list` or `csv`  instead of `table`. When writing to a pipe, it uses the console output codepage, which matches how CMD decodes from the pipe of a `for /f` loop. Use UTF-8 via `chcp.com 65001`.

Comment: @eryksun, are you sure `openfiles` lists files open by local processes? When I run it, it explicitly reports that it shows "Files opened remotely via local share points:". I'm looking for open files from a process running locally.

Comment: Did you enable local tracking and reboot?

Comment: @TomBlodget, I opened powershell, tried dir and openfiles and verified I was getting Greek characters (I live in Greece and the filenames have Greek letters - powershell starts with codepage 737 by default). I tried chcp with all the Greek codepages (even those that I'm sure wouldn't work like DOS codepages) from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx plus 65000 & 65001 (UTF) but I was always getting ???? instead of Greek chars.

Comment: @eryksun sorry I never understood that `openfiles /local on` was going to allow querying local processes also. I've issued the command but I'll have to wait till the evening to reboot (it's a file server used by a lot of users).

Comment: When writing to the console, openfiles.exe uses Unicode (UTF-16) via `WriteConsoleW`. When writing to a pipe it use the console codepage. The shell you use (CMD, PowerShell) is irrelevant to what openfiles does when writing to a pipe. You just have to run chcp.com or any other means of calling `SetConsoleOutputCP` in the console before running openfiles.exe. It happens that CMD also uses the console codepage when decoding from a `for /f` loop, so you can use that in a batch script to loop over and filter the output from openfiles.exe with the codepage set to 65001 (UTF-8).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158001/discussion-between-ndemou-and-eryksun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `openfiles` for this task. By default openfiles reports only files opened by the files & printers sharing service but after enabling* a feature termed *Maintain Objects List* it will report all open files.

It has two drawbacks though:

1. According to [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732490(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_local) *"Enabling the Maintain Objects List global
   flag may slow down your system"*.
2. You can tell handle.exe to only query open files of a specific
   process but openfiles.exe always queries everything. I found openfiles
   to be a few seconds slower that `handle.exe` in such cases.

Many thanks to eryksun for proposing openfiles. Unfortunately he wasn't available to post an answer.

---

**Notes**

*: You need to run `openfiles /local on` and reboot